# erro em math.sqrt

Tags: python, matemática

Estou usando o módulo math em python, e me surgiu um problema, ao usar math.sqrt para a raíz de 75, o mesmo me retorna 7.5, mesmo usando o float(), sendo que a raíz é algo em torno de 8.66
Como posso corrigir este problema ? (os valores lançados pelo usuário são 5,5,5)

```
#Definimos a função que calcula o Delta
def deltaFn(a,b,c):
    d = float(math.pow(b,2)+((-4) * a * c))
    return d
#Função de cálculo da fórmula de Bhaskara para retornar os valores x1 e x2
def bhaskaraFn(a,b,c):
    #A unidade imaginária é False até o momento de sabermos o valor de delta, podendo variar para True
    i = False
    #Executa a função deltaFn para poder tirar a sua raíz
    delta = deltaFn(a,b,c)
    #Verificação de caso de raiz negativa
    if delta < 0:
        #Definir a unidade imaginária como True
        i = True
        #Tornamos o valor positivo para posteriormente indicarmos como unidade imaginária
        delta *= (-1)
        raizDelta = float(math.sqrt(delta)) ### <----------
        #A conta deve ser efetuada separadamente, para não haver risco de somar o valor Imaginário com o valor Real
        # - B / 2 * a
        termoB = (b * (-1)) / (2 * a)
        #Número imaginário (delta dividido por 2 * a e concatenado com 'i')
        imaginario = (delta / (2 * a))
        imaginario = str(imaginario) + 'i'
        #Valores de x1 e x2
        x1 = '%d + '%(termoB) + imaginario
        print('x1 = ',x1)
        x2 = '%d - '%(termoB) + imaginario
        print('x2 = ',x2)
        return (i,x1,x2)
    else:
        raizDelta = math.sqrt(delta)
        x1 = ((b * (-1)) + delta) / (2 * a)
        x2 = ((b * (-1)) - delta) / (2 * a)
        return (i,x1,x2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está confundindo suas variáveis. Primeiro faz

```
delta *= (-1)
raizDelta = float(math.sqrt(delta))
```

E depois usa `delta`, quando calculou a raiz e a colocou na variável `raizDelta`:

```
imaginario = (delta / (2 * a))
```

O que quer fazer é usar a variável `raizDelta`:

```
imaginario = (raizDelta / (2 * a))
```

Comment: verdade mano, muito obrigado <3